# iOS - UINavigationController, Hide navigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a minor trouble hiding the navigationBar for my UINavigationController

I have added:

```
self.navigation!.navigationBar.hidden = true
```

This, unfortunately leaves some kind of background (white) left behind the white status bar that pushes the content (green) downwards, and an unwanted scroll behaviour where I can drag the content up and down to show/hide the white background. What I need is for the statusbar to take up no vertical space what so ever and lay on top of the content (green)

How do I achieve this? 
Answers in swift as well obj-c are very welcome

[image]
**EDIT:**
I have tried various versions of the following, the problem remains -.-

```
override func loadView() {
    self.view = UIView(frame:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


    self.navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.guideViewController!)

    self.navigation!.navigationBarHidden = true
    self.navigation!.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

    self.view.addSubview(self.navigation!.view)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    self.navigation!.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

printing:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
```

after viewDidLoad returns 20

Comment: Whats "!" IN > self.navigation!.navigationBar.hidden = true ?

Comment: It just means to unwrap an optional value, a variable that isn't set when it's defined is optional and needs to be unwrapped when requested

Comment: How do you set your views contraints ?

Comment: Edited my edit to show the view constraints

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Updated :**

Just add this in you `ViewDidLoad` method

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: I falsely believed the issue was occurring in my UINavigationController, after some looking i realised the fault lied in one of my pushed views, adding automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets in the view did the trick! Thanks iBhavin

Answer (score 6):

You can use  hide navigation bar like

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

Hide status bar

```
// Hide status bar iOS 7 or later
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this site: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/navigation_controller/make_the_nav_bar_disappear/

This site says that "The behavior is slightly different depending on whether the Nav Bar is opaque or translucent"

I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question has already been answered but I was having the same issue when hiding a navigation bar then using a `UIScrollView` in the view.

I fixed it programmatically using:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Or in interface builder by deselecting all of these: 
[image]